# Do I need to define the complete UDP stack for communication?

Tags: omnet++

Hello all I am new to Omnet++ and I am trying to implement a network with three kind of nodes: server, router and clients.

I want to use UDP for communication among nodes. So I wanted to know do I need to implement complete stack for each kind of nodes or is there any other method to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to implement IP/UDP/TCP stack by hand. [INET](https://inet.omnetpp.org/) is a powerful model for `OMNeT++` which includes everything you need to build nodes and use UDP to communication.

Comment: I have made the project dependencies on the INET project . So do I just need to respective Protocol (UDP in my case) in my NED file and inherit the respective class in the source CC file?

Comment: If you don't intend to modify protocols of lower layers (i.e. IP, TCP, UDP etc.), then I suggest using ready to use models of hosts and routers. For example, you can use `StandardHost` as well as `Router` model. Take a look at `BulkTransfer` in `examples\inet` directory. In order to implement own communication via UDP, you need to prepare own UDP Application (i.e. definition in `*.ned` and behaviour in `*.h/*.cc`), take a look at `src\inet\applications\udpapp\UDPBasicApp.ned`. Then in `omnetpp.ini` you have to add `**.node1.**.numUdpApps = 1` and `**.node1.**.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPYourApp"`

Comment: I have checked those. Then in my NED file I extended StandardHost for my modules as below:
module host extends StandardHost
{
 ---
 ---
}
with the required imports. is it the right method to do so or does Omnetpp provide certain methodology to do so? Also in the source file do I need to inherit from say, UDPBasicApp to code the behavior?

Comment: You don't have to extend `StandardHost`, just place it on you network area using mouse (or by edit `ned`), and call it for example `node1`. As a consequence in your network `ned` file should be something like this: `submodules:  node1 : StandardHost;`. In `ned` of `UDPYourApp`: `UDPYourApp` has to implement `IUDPApp` interface (i.e. `simple UDPYourApp like IUDPApp { //...` ). And in your C++ code: `UDPYourApp` has to inherit from `ApplicationBase`. Take a look at `UDPBasicApp` ned/h/cc definitions.

Comment: Ohh yeah you told that earlier. Similar to BulkTransfer, right?

Comment: `BulkTransfer` is a good and simple example of network which uses `StandardHost` and `Router`. And `UDPBroadcastNetwork` is more advanced example in which `StandardHost`, `Router` as well as `UDPApp` are used.

Comment: this was very helpful.. Now I am able to cope up with Omnet++. Really appreciate it